# Convert "True" and "False" to Python Boolean, But Leave Other Strings Unmodified

Tags: python, string, csv, type-conversion, boolean

I'm working on an application using Flask-SQLAlchemy which needs to import and export data in `.csv` format. I have the export function working, but I've hit a snag with the import.

In short, I'm looking for a generic way to import the strings "True" and "False" as Boolean values, but *any other* string value as itself. The reason for this is that `csv.DictWriter` renders Boolean values as their string equivalents, and I need to import the resulting file back into the database.

I've tried `ast.literal_eval()`, but it throws a ValueError if I give it anything other than "True" or "False". I could test for the column name, but of course that would break as soon as I change my schema. I want to use the idiom

```
reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
...
for row in reader:
...
    contact = Contact.query.get(row['id'])
    for key, value in row.items():
        setattr(contact, key, value)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve what I want to accomplish?

Comment: You shouldn't use CSV format if data types are important. Use JSON or Pickle.

Comment: I need to export to a spreadsheet, and then import the modified spreadsheet. That's why I'm using .csv.

Comment: This sounds like an [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @KlausD. How would you suggest I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Barmar's answer above, I tried

```
for row in reader:
    if not row['id']:
        contact = Contact(**row)
        db.session.add(contact)
    else:
        contact = Contact.query.get(row['id'])
        for key, value in row.items():
            if value == "True":
                value = True
            if value == "False":
                value = False
            if value == '':
                value = None
            setattr(contact, key, value)
```

But then I realized I should be doing it in my model, in an `@validates` method:

```
class Contact(db.Model):
...
    @validates('blacklisted', 'disabled', 'is_member')
    def string_to_bool(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(value, bool):
            return value
        if value == "True":
            return True
        if value == "False":
            return False
        if value is not None and re.match("^\s*$", value) is not None:
            return None
        return value
```

This puts all the type-matching code in one place, where it is most relevant.

Answer (score 0):

when reading the CSV, loop through all the columns and replace the strings with the corresponding values.

```
csv_data = []
with open("file.csv") as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_f:
        for i, col in enumerate(row):
            if col == "True":
                row[i] = True
            elif col == "False":
                row[i] = False
        csv_data.append(row)
```

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, not put it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use pandas to read and write? you can easily convert a column using the `as_type()` method

UPDATE:
Assuming the `test.csv` is

```sh
1,True,sada
2,False,asda
3,False,afaff
4,True,agwe
```

read the CSV with

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read('text.csv', header=None)
```

Check data:

```py
print(data.head())
```

```sh
  0      1      2
0  1   True   sada
1  2  False   asda
2  3  False  afaff
3  4   True   agwe
```

Check types:

```py
print(data.dtypes)
```

```sh
0     int64
1      bool
2    object
dtype: object
```

Convert column to string or integers or boolean:

```py
data[1].as_type(str)
data[1].as_type(int)
data[1].as_type(bool)
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to do this?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax see updated post